# SharePoint + Excel with Macro

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to move an Excel spreadsheet from a mapped drive to SharePoint.

We have an engineering department who uses this spreadsheet to keep an active list of job and job numbers.

It breaks down like this:

User opens Job Tracking Spreadsheet and enters information
On the final tab, there's a red button that goes to another Excel workbook that provides the next available job number and is generated in the Job Tracking Spreadsheet where the red button is.

The code that runs when the red button is clicked:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim JTS As String
    Dim yRow, UseRow
    Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, Msg1, Msg2, Msg3

    UnProtect_Files

    If Worksheets("HANDOVER").Range("Job_No") <> "" Then GoTo JobFill1
    If Len(Worksheets("HANDOVER").Range("C4")) < 1 Then GoTo WhereCust1

    JTS = "P:\Job Tracking\Job Tracking Spreadsheet.xls"

    On Error GoTo Lock1

    OpBkNow:
    Workbooks.Open (JTS)

    'Look for available Job# in Job Tracking Spreadsheet

    For yRow = 23 To 10000
    If Workbooks("Job Tracking Spreadsheet.xls").Worksheets("Proposed-Active").Cells(yRow, 2) = "" Then UseRow = yRow: Exit For Next yRow
    'This should never happen, but if there is no available Job#, print msg and exit sub
    If UseRow < 23 Or UseRow > 10000 Then GoTo RowNtFnd


    'Make changes to Job Tracking Spreadsheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formulas").Range("B98") = Workbooks("Job Tracking Spreadsheet.xls").Worksheets("Proposed-Active").Cells(UseRow, 1)
    Workbooks("Job Tracking Spreadsheet.xls").Worksheets("Proposed-Active").Cells(UseRow, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HANDOVER").Range("C4")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HANDOVER").Range("Job_No") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formulas").Range("B98")
    Workbooks("Job Tracking Spreadsheet.xls").Worksheets("Proposed-Active").Cells(UseRow, 3) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HANDOVER").Range("D7")

    GoTo QuitSb2

    RowNtFnd:
    Msg = "There are no available Job Numbers in the Job Tracking Spreadsheet.  You will need to manually add one."
    Style = vbOKOnly: Title = "Job Number Not Found": Help = "": Ctxt = 0
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)

    QuitSb2:
    Workbooks("Job Tracking Spreadsheet.xls").Close SaveChanges:=True
    GoTo QuitSb1

    WhereCust1:
    'No Owner Name Given
    Msg = "An entry in the CUSTOMER field is required when generating a Job Number!"
    Style = vbOKOnly: Title = "Need Customer Info - Try Again": Help = "": Ctxt = 0
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)
    GoTo QuitSb1

    JobFill1:
    'There is already a generated job number
    Msg1 = "A Job Number ("
    Msg2 = Worksheets("HANDOVER").Range("Job_No")
    Msg3 = ") has already been generated for this job!"

    Msg = Msg1 & Msg2 & Msg3
    Style = vbOKOnly: Title = "Job Number Exists": Help = "": Ctxt = 0
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)
    GoTo QuitSb1

    Lock1:
    'There is already a generated job number
    Msg1 = "The Job Tracking spreadsheet is currently in use.  "
    Msg2 = "Please try to generate a Job Number later."
    Msg = Msg1 & Msg2
    Style = vbOKOnly: Title = "File In Use": Help = "": Ctxt = 0
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)
    GoTo QuitSb1

    QuitSb1:

    'RER 3-29-05 remove auto file create as per Scott Penatzer request
    'Create_New_File

    Protect_Files
End Sub
```

It may be easier to do all of this another way but ultimately the business would prefer I change nothing.  Is it possible to have multiple documents on SharePoint communicating with each other and avoiding network shares completely?  Please advise as soon as you can.

Thank you very much so in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Use Ctrl-K to format your code block and add some line breaks and indentation. You're more likely to get an answer that way. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks.  I made the format to reflect that it is code.  Hopefully someone can better assist me now.  I'm open to all suggestions, just trying to make this work in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have files communicate over SharePoint.  Go to the Library in SharePoint, click "Open in Explorer" from the ribbon.  That will give you the folder location of the file.  You should be able to reference that URL just like a mapped drive location and open/update/save the SharePoint file.  Good luck.